# Google Map Javascript API not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

copy paste from google instructions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="capture"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC8kDz25qFYhy1UYiPyrzvcOpkiwZz9C4o&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I'm still getting this error of google:
"Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."

Why it's so complicated?

[Here is my API Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t7hC.png)

Comment: you are calling the function initMap before it was loaded in the google maps js file.

Comment: What does the javascript console say?

Comment: its wonderfull, in google example only height is set to 100%, when i set height and width in pixels its working, `#map { height: 500px; width: 400px; } `

Comment: @sairfan Thanks. I was banging my head. css was my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You did not activate the API key. I do not recall exactly where in the process this happens or how but it is one of the steps when you created the key.

`Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError`

And included in the console message is the link to your instructions on what to do: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error`

Comment: so complicated, you know what.. I clicked on some button on google website, then that sent me back to the console API and I don't even know how I fixed it, but it's working now, thank you anyway

Comment: That is the activation button you clicked @NelsonDenver